# How do I get the current directory of the prompt

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script where the first parameter is a filename. But whenever I try to use that string in something that takes a file, I get an error about the file not being found. How do I get the current directory the powershell prompt is in? For some reason it keeps returning my user profile directory:

```
C:\Users\user1> [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
C:\Users\user1

C:\Users\user1> cd\

C:\> cd temp

C:\temp> [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
C:\Users\user1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pwd` is the cmdlet you search for ;)

This is an alias for `Get-Location`.

Comment: You should mention that `pwd` is an alias for `Get-Location`.

Comment: :D I just submitted an edit for that while you wrote that. Thanks!!

Comment: I also edited my answer before you both wrote the comment ;-)

Comment: We're all too fast!! Once I can accept the answer, I will. Thanks again! This was driving me nuts..*pirate voice*